# starting with Magento Backend

Tags: magento, widget, backend

Since a couple of days I´m looking at the behaviour of the Magento backend. To comprehend I made a new grid to see a table of the bbdd. After finishing this grid I can see that I have a 404 error when try I to add a widget in a CMS page:

[image]

Debugging I can see that the error disappears if I comment this out of my custom module

```
<admin>
    <routers>
       <giftrouter>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Wpr_Giftproducts_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>admin</frontName>
                <modules>
                    <sintax after="Wpr_Giftproducts_Adminhtml">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                </modules>
            </args>
       </giftrouter>             

     </routers>     
</admin>
```

Concretely I think that the error was caused by this:

```
<sintax after="Wpr_Giftproducts_Adminhtml">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
```

But I don´t understand how this config works. 
How can I set a custom route to avoid conflict with the widget?

Comment: Make sure you have acl section for your admin page.

Comment: Thanks Junuxx for the correction and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have your routers in reverse.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <sintax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Wpr_Giftproducts_Adminhtml</sintax>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This way the `Giftproducts` controller is part of the `adminhtml` router, whereas the old way was reassigning admin controllers to `giftrouter`.

Comment: you don´t put frontname. why not?? what is the diference??. i don´t how to work this, and the unique knowledge is for example that i find in internet. if i put <sintax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Wpr_Giftproducts_Adminhtml</sintax> the backend stops working.

Comment: Only one router can have the front name of `admin`, and that is already used by `adminhtml`. Your router was `giftrouter` but here I have dropped that whole thing. Delete the entire `<giftrouter>` section.