# Magento - Custom admin router but with no menu item

Tags: magento

I want to create an admin controller - without having any menu items associated with it.

Ideally I want to have my controller accessible via /index.php/admin/my_controller/.

So far I have rewritten the adminhtml controller as follows but i simnply get a 404 inside the admin console (i.e. not the main 404 page):

```
    <admin>
    <routers> 
        <my_module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Me_Mymodule</module>
                <frontName>my_controller</frontName>
            </args>
        </my_module>
         <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_module after="Mage_Adminhtml">Me_Mymodule</my_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you goal xml config is redundant.
Use following to add your controller to /admin frontname
        
        
            
                
                    
                        Company_Module_Adminhtml
                    
                
            
        
    

Now every controller that will be created in controller/Adminhtml folder will accessed through admin like

```
/admin/yourfilename/index
```

The class name of controller should be `Module_Module_Adminhtml_YourfilenameController` and should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`
That's the trick.

Comment: XML config is necessary to add directory to list of directories for Mage_Adminhtml.

Answer (score 3):

Your current config technique has been obsolete since version 1.4. Instead it is more convenient to structure it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535123/471559).

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Me_Mymodule_Adminhtml</my_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Then to get the `/index.php/admin/mymodule/` path create the class `Me_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` in `Me/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/MymoduleController.php`. In your example you used an underscore in the controller name, be careful of that as it will be used as a directory separator when searching for the correct class.

Remember to generate URLs for your controller like `Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/mymodule')` so that it adds the secret key to paths, this is necessary when making an admin controller or it will refuse the page.

If there are no menu items then it will not be possible to add them to the ACL. You do not need an `adminhtml.xml` file in this case.

Comment: The OP config is correct. The first part is a bit extraneous, but overall is correct...

Comment: One notice.
Better use after="Mage_Adminhtml" to avoid unintentionally overriding of magento module.

Comment: @Sergy That is my habit because sometimes you need to override core controllers. Thanks for pointing it out and the OP has the option of which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not add your controller to menu, you still have to add acl section for your controller `adminhtml.xml`. Do not forget to relog to admin after that.